# Array.Sort is not working

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

I am very new at programming and learning it via Visual Basic for Beginners by wrox.com. So I am learning Arrays. In the practical part of the book there is a method for sorting arrays. I am doing the same as it was instructed in the books. But programm says the Sort is not a member of Array (Which means Array.Sort is incorrect). But I took a look at several examples in internet where Array.Sort is working for them.

[image]

Comment: Could you have a case sensitive problem? (In your example the code is "Array.sort" not "Array.Sort")

Comment: Visual Basic 2015 automatically fixes case errors. I think it is not the reason of problem. For example if I write "dim" it automatically turns to "Dim", "integer" to "Integer" etc.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y1ys6z fiddle shows  Array.Sort works, If I am not mistaken

Comment: I tried Array.Sort() as well. But it still shows error. In error list it says following: Error BC30456 'Sort' is not a member of 'Array'.

Comment: Then may be there is an error with the setup you are working with..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I saw in image, StrFriends is a LIST not an ARRAY.
Array.Sort is valid for arrays only, not to Lists.
If you need to sort a list, you need to convert it to array, like this:

```
            Dim cave As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
            Array.Sort(cave.ToArray)
```

or just operate as ARRAY:

```
            dim cave as String() = {"j", "c", "a", "b"}
            Array.Sort(cave)
```

or

```
            dim cave(0 to 3) as String
            cave(0) = "j"
            cave(1) = "c"
            cave(2) = "a"
            cave(3) = "b"
            Array.Sort(cave)
```

Comment: Oh it was array. The declaration of strFriends was at the top after Public Class. It was declared like: Dim strFriends (4) As String

Comment: Has you program the "include" line necessary? At the op of your code must exist "Imports System Collections".

Comment: ANother thing I see: is your StrFiends array correclty dimensioned? Different from LIST, you cannot simply "add" as you does in "AddItemsToList" and I see you are calling this routine to add names into StrFriends.  I guess you are confuse about LISTS and ARRAY (they are different!)

Answer (score 0):

try this code:
System.Sort.Array(strFriend)

Hope this works!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).